# Footnotetext without text where it can stick to

Tags: captions, footnotes

I am having the problem that almost at the end of my document, I want to add a figure with a footnote in its captin. While this is no problem inside the document where always new text comes where I can put the `\footnotetext{}` so that the footnote from `\protect\footnotemark` is forced onto the same page as its mark, this is a problem at the end where no usual text follows anymore. I tried to put the `figure` inside a `minipage` and use `\vspace` to put the footnote at the end of the page (suggested in another discussion), but all that happens is that the footnote is displayed at the end of the previous page. Also I tried to add `\phantom` or `\color{white}{any text}` to create some invisible text after the image where the footnote could stick to. But without success. Here is a not so short MWE - the problem does not happen here as most of the document is deleted. Summary: what i need is to force the footnote from `\protect\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` onto the same page as the image. Problem: footnote is on previous page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
%%Math, astro, chemical packages and options
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%Citations and Referencing
\usepackage[]{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5\linewidth]{Img1}
\caption{Img1 Caption.}
\label{Fig:Img1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Img2}
\caption{Img2 Caption.\protect\footnotemark}
\label{Fig:Img2}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\url{xyz}, Date.}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Table1 Caption}
\label{Table:Table1}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\cmidrule{1-4} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-4}
File Id. & Time [UT] & x & y \\
\midrule
fts & long time ago & & \\
\cmidrule{1-4} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \item Note 1: abc
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A MWE that is not minimal, that doesn't show the error and that can not be compiled due to local graphics is completly useless. Your strategy can't work reliable. The float can always float away and so overtake the footnote text. Imho people who tries to put footnotes from floating objects at the bottom of the page get the trouble they deserve.

Comment: try to add `\clearpage` just befor your figure.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer THe MWE is as small as possible while still containing the packages that were releveant for me. Also thank you for the rookie friendly opinion encouraging others to vote for. At least I took the effort to comment my trials!

Comment: @touhami Thank you very much! This solved the issue.

Comment: @Lucas: A minimal example should not contain the package that are relevant for you but the packages (and the code) relevant for the problem. But more importantly it should be an *example*.  If you can't produce one it doesn't make sense to decorate (polute) your question with 70 lines of unrelated code.